# AWS ALB - Access Logs versus Request Tracing versus CloudTrail Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services

Amazon introduced support for Request Tracing in 2016 for all of its Application Load Balancers (ALBs).

How are **Access Logging**, **Request Tracing** and **CloudTrail logging**, different from each other?

When to use what?

How is one better than the other and under what circumstances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CloudTrail logs API calls within your account. Load balancer log files log HTTP client requests to your load balancer (e.g. web traffic). Very different types of information.

Load Balancer access logs record information about who, where and what HTTP requests are being made from clients. This information is useful for traffic analysis.

Request Tracing adds a custom header X-Amzn-Trace-Id into the request to your origin (typically a web server). This is used to trace (track) requests thru your origin servers.

Comment: Updated the question. How then is Access logging  different from  Request Tracing? I really appreciate your brief and to the point answer. Thanks!

Comment: The difference between access logging and request tracing is that the former results in, possibly, all of your applications emitting information they've been accessed, and the latter adds a unique identifier that should be passed down through the stack. Emitting the trace id in your access logs allows you to connect/correlate access logs from different applications that belong to a single logical request. For example, me visiting https://example.com/api/v4/projects API is one logical request, but might result in 10 services being called downstream.